# VSTS/TFS - Build How do you specify a commit message for which the CI build should not get triggered?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to not trigger CI for some of the commits that I push to VSTS.

Is their something which I can specify in commit message which will prevent CI to not trigger?

Answer (score 4):

**How do I avoid triggering a CI build when the script pushes?**

Add `***NO_CI***` to your commit message. For example, `git merge origin/features/hello-world -m "Merge to master ***NO_CI***"`

Docs: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands